# Necesito mostrar los datos en mi tabla. los datos los obtengo pero no los muestra en mi tabla con vue

Tags: asp.net, vue.js, asp, vuetify

Estoy actualizando la parte Front-End de un sistema y actualice a la ultima versión de vue (v2.6.11). El problema es en el momento que quiero listar los campos en mis componentes. Asi es como se muestra mi codigo para listar y mi script, back estoy utilizando asp.net 3.1, no me tira ningun error en consola ni en network y relice la peticion a vue y si estan apareciendo los datos mi problema siempre es al momento de listar no muestra nada, estoy utilizando la propiedad props para poder listarlo. Ya revise los nombres de los campos que sean totalmente iguales, confirme si estaba funcionando la peticion Get y tampoco se tiene ningun problema, por que razon no me podra listar lo que tengo la base de datos, (estoy utilizando sql server).

```
     <template v-slot:item.opciones="{ item }">
        <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">edit</v-icon>   
        <v-icon small @click="deleteItem(item)">delete</v-icon>
        </template>
         <template v-slot:items="props">
            <td>{{ props.item.mediumId }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.personalInformationId }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.medium1 }}</td>
        </template>                

        <template v-slot:no-data>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="listar()">Enciendelo Eduardo</v-btn>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
</v-flex>
```

**Mi Script **

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    data: () => ({
            medium:[],
            dialog: false,
            headers: [
            { text: 'Opciones', value: 'opciones', sortable: false },
            { text: 'Medio de Información', value: 'mediumId' },
            { text: 'Medio de Información', value: 'personalInformationId' },
            { text: 'Medio de Información', value: 'medium1' },
            { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false }
            ],
                editedIndex: -1,
          
               mediumId: '',
               personalInformationId: '',
               medium1:''        
            
    }),

    computed: {
    formTitle () {
        return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'Registrar' : 'Actualizar'
    },
    },
    watch: {
    dialog (val) {
        val || this.close()
    },
    },
    created () {
        this.listar();
    },

    methods: {
        listar (){
            let me=this;
            axios.get('api/Medium/').then(function(response){
             //console.log(response);
             me.medium=response.data;
           }).catch(function(error){
             console.log(error);
            });
    },
    editItem (item) {
        this.editedIndex = this.desserts.indexOf(item)
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
        this.dialog = true
    },

    deleteItem (item) {
        const index = this.desserts.indexOf(item)
        confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') && this.desserts.splice(index, 1)
    },

    close () {
        this.dialog = false
    },
    limpiar(){
          this.idmedio= "";
          this.idinformacionpersonal= "";
          this.medio="";
    },

    guardar () {
            if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
                //Código para editar
            } else {
                //Código para guardar
                let me=this;
                axios.post('api/Medium',{
                    'medio': me.medio
                }).then(function(){
                    me.close();
                    me.listar();
                    me.limpiar();                        
                }).catch(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: donde lo estas listando.. no veo el array medium por ningun lado...

Comment: se supone que utilizando la propiedad props se tendria que mostrar los datos. o como haria el array ?

Comment: no entiendo que tratas de hacer.. me resulta confuso, si usas props es porque estas obteniendo datos en tu componente que vienen del padre, pero vos mostras codigo que no se donde esta.. y lo que queres mostrar, ese array, no esta en ningun lado de tu codigo...

Comment: lo que necesito es mostrar los datos en mi tabla. los datos los obtengo pero no los muestra en mi tabla

Comment: ahhhh es que tu codigo esta incompleto!!! arregla la pregunta a ver si empezamos de vuelta...

Comment: listo ya la edite espero asi ya se pueda entender mejor.

Comment: lo que esta mal es donde mostras los datos.. fijate que es una v-data-table, pero no se ve donde se inicia la misma...

Comment: <v-data-table
                :headers="headers"
                :item="medium"
                class= "elevation-1"
         >    

asi es como esta inciando la v-data-table